# Exibir a classe de diferentes tags de um ID a cada clique

Tags: jquery, html

Quero fazer um código em que pegue a classe de um ID sempre que for clicado:

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-1">1</li>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-2">2</li>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        var $alertando = '';
        $j("#alert-class").click(function() {
            $alertando = $j(this).attr("class");
            alert($alertando);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Até que funciona bem, o alerta imprime a informação certa, porém só imprime o valor do primeiro "li", quando eu clico no mesmo. Os outros "li"s e seus respectivos alertas das classes não funcionam.

Bom, eu tentei fazer de várias formas diferentes, tentei usar o "each" mas não obtive sucesso em simplificar o meu código.

Onde eu quero utilizá-lo é bem mais complexo que isso, mas achei melhor simplificar e facilitar o entendimento e acaba funcionando do mesmo modo, imagino.

Aguardo respostas e desde já agradeço!

Comment: Simplesmente por que um **id**, deve ser único, então o seletor acha o primeiro e para, você está utilizado id para os fins errados. Reveja sua estrutura.

Comment: Na verdade, pelo que eu entendi, o que você tá usando em `class`, deveria ser `id` e vice-versa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente por que um **id**, deve ser único (**sempre**), então o seletor acha o primeiro e para.

[Definição do atributo **id**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Uma opção seria, colocar o `id`, ai sim único no `ul`, assim:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  var $alertando = '';
  // modificando seu seletor para pegar todos os li filhos diretos de ul com id = alert-class
  $j("ul#alert-class > li").click(function() {
    $alertando = $j(this).attr("class");
    alert($alertando);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="alert-class">
  <li class="class-1">1</li>
  <li class="class-2">2</li>
  <li class="class-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

**Observação**

Pelo que pude notar, você parece também estar utilizando o atributo `class`, para os fins que ele não foi [conceitualmente criado](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes) (e [MDN definição de `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)), no caso, se você pretende armazenar/guardar dados de negocio em um elemento HTML, utilize [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Como demonstrado no exemplo a seguir:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  var $alertando = '';
  // modificando seu seletor para pegar todos os li filhos diretos de ul com id = alert-class
  $j("ul#alert-class > li").click(function() {
    $alertando = $j(this).data("message");
    alert($alertando);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="alert-class">
  <li data-message="class-1">1</li>
  <li data-message="class-2">2</li>
  <li data-message="class-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu no comentário @Fernando, e você estava certo. Agradeço muito pela ajuda!

Comment: @LunaLaura, fico feliz por ter ajudado. Mas mantenha isso sempre em mente **`id` = único** e `class` sim você poderia utilizar como agrupador, para o seletor. =D

Comment: Copy That @Fernando :D

Comment: @LunaLaura, observe a edição, onde adicionei uma observação sobre a utilização da `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar você deve definir `id` únicos para cada elemento.

Mas o que você quer pode ser feito assim:

```js
$("li").click(function () {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-1">1</li>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-2">2</li>
    <li id="alert-class" class="class-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sua solução funciona também, mais observe que o `id` continua o mesmo.

Comment: Sim, deixei o mesmo id de propósito para não mexer no código original, ;) No início fiz uma observação para não usar ids iguais.